# How to get nested select in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get access to nested select, presented on attached link to screen. My code shows error "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element". Appreciate for help. [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2w4k.png)

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.content_middle > div > div > table > tr > select.singlerobbery-select-robbery"))

all_selected = select.all_selected_options
    for option in range(len(all_selected)):
        print(select.select_by_index(option))
```

Comment: Did you check for iframes?

Comment: @Sureshmani I did not

Comment: If this element is within a iframe, you should switch to it before finding this element.

Comment: @Sureshmani well I do not see iframe in html, so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: can you post the html with select options?

Comment: Nevermind, resolved that by myself :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

this selector worked

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr//table//tr//select[@id='singlerobbery-select-robbery']"))
```

However i can't get the rest of options. This select is hidden in td and when I try to get all options, I receive only the default one :(